# score calculator php game

Tags: php, math

So I am making a little guessing game where a player has to guess a number between a maximum an minimum. The player will see if it needs to guess higher or lower based on there input given.

The player can choose its own minimum or maximum and start the game.
Now I want to make a scoreboard.

Does someone have a calculation idea on how to make a balanced score?

---

variables:

- Minimum
- Maximum
- Tries
- Time (in sec)

---

I thought of doing something with percents. Like what is the change that you can guess the number between the `max` and `min`. And then adding or multiplying that with the tries and time. But I dont know if that would be balanced enough.

If someone would like to help with this equation. I would really apreciate it!

---

**few examples:**

```
Minimum: 0
Maximum: 100
Tries: 6
Time: 26 (sec)
Score: ???
```

```
Minimum: 50
Maximum: 500
Tries: 12
Time: 45 (sec)
Score: ???
```

```
Minimum: 100
Maximum: 1000
Tries: 8
Time: 32 (sec)
Score: ???
```

If there is any confusion please ask (:

Comment: I think this is quite a boring game. Guessing a number between 100 and 1000 is no fun, and nearly impossible (< 1%) to do in 8 tries. The game would become slightly more interesting if you gave some feedback, like "too high" and "too low".

Comment: In such "games" the program usually answers *more* or *less* which leads to at most 10 tries in the worst case (for 100 - 1000)

Comment: Anyway, this question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) because it's based on opinion rather than a real problem

Comment: @KIKOSoftware It does say that you need to guess higher or lower. It is for a school project though so I did not really have a choice to make an other game (;

Comment: Ah well, that's exactly what Cid and I meant. That information was missing from your question.

Comment: I tried to answer your question, but I must agree with CID that this is inviting opinions. It is more difficult than I expected. Your examples vary in difficulty, which should be reflected in the final score. I did find a way to compute the average number of tries needed to find a number: `log($maximum - $minimum, 2)`. That can be useful to you.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thank you very much for your time. I will look in to this. Although I doubt that I will be able to fix it because it is so hard to belance. <3 thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Based on the binary numbering system you can guess the maximum number of tries somebody needs to guess the correct number. So for a number between 1 and 100, one would need, at most, `log(100,2)`, or 6.6 tries. Anybody doing better than that deserves a high score, and lower than that and they didn't follow the feedback correctly. Let's keep that simple, assuming:

```
$minimum = 1;
$maximum = 100;
$tries   = 6;
$time    = 26;
```

you can compute a score for the number of tries like this:

```
$maxTries   = log($maximum - $minimum, 2);
$scoreTries = $maxTries / $tries;
```

The value here would be 1.1. Note that `$maxTries` says something about the complexity of the task. We will use this number later on.

The `$scoreTries` clearly doesn't incorporate time yet. Let's start by computing the time needed per try.

```
$scoreTime = $time / $maxTries;
```

Note that I am using the maximum number of tries needed here because we don't want the actual number of tries to have an effect on this score. The score here would be 26 / 6.6 or 3.9.

Obviously, the quicker someone enters their tries, the higher the score should be. That is not yet the case. However, we can get there by simply inverting of the above:

```
$scoreTime = $maxTries / $time;
```

So the score here is 6.6 / 26 or 0.25. The quicker they find the number, the higher this score will be.

We now have one number and two scores:

- `$maxTries` which gets higher when the complexity of the task increase.
- `$scoreTries` which gets higher when less tries are needed.
- `$scoreTime` which gets higher the quicker someone is.

It is unclear how we should 'weigh' these values. I'll leave that to you. The final score can be computed like this:

```
$complexityWeight = 1; // value to be determined by you.
$attemptsWeight   = 2; // value to be determined by you.
$speedWeight      = 3; // value to be determined by you.

$finalScore = ($complexityWeight * $maxTries) +
              ($attemptsWeight * $scoreTries) +
              ($speedWeight * $scoreTime);
```

There are, of course, other ways to combine these three numbers.

Comment: Holy moly thank you for the answer I have not tried it yet but this seems like a really good solution! I will inform you when I made it working.

Comment: Instead of adding 10 to `$scoreTries = $avgTries - $tries`, which is a bit artificial, you could do `$scoreTries = $avgTries / $tries`. This is also more similar to what I did with the timing. That's also why people think your question is opinion based; there are many ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks the code works at the moment but I do not understand what the php `log()` function does. There is not much info on the internet. Does it literally calculate how many tries it would averagely take to find the number or is it another sort of calculation?

Comment: I might have made a mistake. Another way to look at it is this: Each number in a 256 range can be reached by making 8 divisions in the range. So, it would be better to say that `log(256,2)` results in the **maximum number of guesses needed**, which is 8. This assumes that the player always reacts correctly to the feedback given.

Comment: I edited my answer, and changed 'average' to 'maximum'.